# Newbie can't link html and css

Tags: html, css

The css doesn't work. I tried putting the stylesheet in a style folder in the main folder and then tried deleting the style folder and put the style sheet in the main folder and that still did not fix it. How do I fix it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Use [code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to show your code instead of img.

Answer (score 2):

You have invalid selectors; The ID `awesome title` is not the same as `awesomeTitle`, and the class `body text` is not the same as `bodyText`.

Fixing the ID and selector names in your HTML will allow your CSS selectors to correctly target:

```css
#awesomeTitle {
  color: blue;
}

.bodyText {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="awesomeTitle">Title</h1>
<p class="bodyText">Body</p>
```